# Facebook app namespace is "Already used by some other app"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I wanted to define the app namespace for our app on facebook, so that I will be able to create a custom Open graph object and got an error saying the namespace is "Already used by some other app".

Is there any way for me to know which app has the namespace I wanted to use (which is our app name...)?
or to "claim" it some how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means the namespace is already taken by someone else.
You need to select unique namespace.
P.S- namespace is something like a unique name for your app.

To add the namespace to your App just follow simple steps : -

1. Go to your App.
2. Select Settings option from the left sidebar.
3. then add a namespace.

Comment: This is all known. but if your app is called "abc" your would expect the "abc" namespace to be available for you. and so do i with respect to my own app's name. I am looking for a way yo tell which other app took my expected/desired namespace.

Comment: Namespace don't depend on App name. You can take only if it is available.Either go with other app name or choose other namespace.

Comment: yep looks like I will use com_myappname instead of just myappname as changing the name and brand of an app that is already running for several years is a problem ...